# Command for Typings CLI utility to make typings folder match typings.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, definitelytyped, typescript-typings

I have a large team working on a repo using Typescript, and nobody checks in the `/typings` folder into the team's shared repository, they only check in the `typings.json` file which specifies the version information for each definition set required by the project.

Sometimes someone will delete a definition set from `typings.json`, since the part of the project they are working on no longer uses that library (or we found a better definition set), using
`typings uninstall --global --save dt~whatever`, and that works fine on their local machine, **BUT** when they push up the new `typings.json` and I or someone else pulls it down, when we then run `typings install`, the command only adds new definitions to the `typings` folder, and does not delete definitions from the `typings` folder which are no longer present in `typings.json`.

Is there a command which I can run to **both** add new definition sets and delete removed sets by diffing the current `typings.json` from the state of `typings.json` when the `typings` command was last run?

Currently we just have everyone delete the entire `typings` folder and run `typings install` again each time they pull, but that is getting to be a bit inefficient, since we have a lot of definition sets now.

*NOTE: we tried `typings uninstall` and `typings uninstall --save` but those just throw errors (it seems you may only specify specific definition sets to uninstall).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
typings prune
```

on your project directory. It will remove all typings that are present on the `typings` directory and not listed on your `typings.json` file.

More info on [the Typings documentation](https://github.com/typings/typings/blob/master/docs/commands.md).

Comment: So everyone can run `typings prune` then `typings install`? Thanks!

Comment: @AjaxLeung just `typings prune` if they need to remove some previously installed typings. `install` only if there are new one to install.